# How to search data in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Using one Dropdownlist and textbox, I need to search data in my gridview.
Suppose I select 1 item in the dropdownlist and enter some text in the textbox.

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I think the title is most helpful thing about his question =)

Answer (score 0):

You sould write to apprpriate sql query against data and rebind your gridview.
Or you can filter out dataser which is already bound with gridview with value of dropdown & textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is easy if you are using a SQL Datasource etc. You just need to mention a [filter expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178306%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and control ids. So, the first control (your dropdownList) would contain filter values like Name,Age,Date etc. The textbox would contain search text. A filter expression like this would mean {0} for the dropdownlist value & {1} for the textbox text

```
CONVERT({0},'System.String') like '{1}%'
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but:

```
string n = "";
int count = 0;

if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    ListBox3.Visible = true;

    int x = GridView1.Rows.Count;
    int o = GridView1.Columns.Count;

    String SearchItem = TextBox1.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < o; c++)
        {
            if (SearchItem == GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text)
            {
                n = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "  R" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text;
            }
        }
        ListBox3.Items.Add(n);
    }
} 
else if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    ListBox3.Visible = true;

    int x = GridView1.Rows.Count;
    int o = GridView1.Columns.Count;

    String SearchItem = TextBox1.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < o; c++)
        {
            if (SearchItem == GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text)
            {
                count++;
                for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
                {
                    ListBox3.Items.Add(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "   R" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text);
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not that helpful